# Collections.shuffle not working as expected

Tags: java, arrays, shuffle

I'm trying to write a simple encryption algo that is a randomized shift pattern encryption. I've written it to be based on an array of all the characters that then uses Collections.shuffle and then matches things to that. However the array doesn't seem to be shuffling as the output text is the same as input

Here is my method

```
static void encrypt(String s)
    {
        //Define variable for indexOf output
        int n;

        //Encrypted output
        String output = "";

        //Shuffle array to create random replacements
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(alphashuff));

        //Create new string
        String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        for (int index = 0; index < s.length();index++)
        {
            char aChar = s.charAt(index);
            n = alpha.indexOf(aChar, 0);

            if(n == -1)
            {
                output = output + aChar;
            }
            else
            {
                output = output + alphashuff[n];
            }

        }

        //Print encrypted string to console
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text: " + output);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not shuffling the array, instead a List created using the array. Create the list before sending it to shuffle:

```
//I'm assuming alphashuff is a char[]
List<Character> lstCh = new ArrayList<Character>();
for(char c : arrCh) {
    lstCh.add(c);
}
Collections.shuffle(lstCh);
//...
else
{
    output = output + lstCh.get(n);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible then to output the shuffled list and return it back as array

Comment: you can use `Arrays.asList` to create list.

Comment: @Quoi that would be an `List<Object>`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - but Arrays.asList returns List<T>

Comment: @Quoi then try `List<char>` or `List<Character> lC = Arrays.asList(alphashuff)`. If you make if compile, I'll take off my hat for you.

Comment: `char[] alphashuff ={'q','w'};
List<Character> lC = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(alphashuff));` and [ArrayUtils.toObject](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toObject%28char%5B%5D%29)

Comment: @Quoi is `ArrayUtils` a native Java class? I though it was from Apache Commons Lang.

Comment: @Quoi then there's no native Java way to do it :). OP doesn't mentioned he/she uses that library. Of course, that would be of great help but it's outside the question scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] alphashuff = ...;
List list = Arrays.asList(alphashuff);
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

This list is shuffled now which consist of values of alphashuff.

And use this like - `output = output + list.get(n);`